# Thread Stops Responding

Tags: android, multithreading

I am new Android Developer. I have not attended any Class but i am learning it myself using Internet.
**Please Copy Paste the same in your android, Try it and guide me why it is not working??**

***it is developed in eclipse. External dependencies are httpclient-4.0.jar and httpcore-4.0.1.jar***
I have developed an application. 
It gets report list from IIS server. which actually links of HTML Pages. (it is global, you may please check the links)

IT has total 16 Html Pages. 
Application is suppose to change Report(Html Page) in WebView every 10 seconds. It changes Report Once. but later it doesn't change.

Please check and tell me what is error.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"

tools:context="com.CorpoServe.bvgindialtd.ReportViewer" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnPrev"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="@string/prev" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnNext"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="@string/next" />

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/Brz"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/btnPrev"
    android:layout_below="@+id/btnPrev" />

<ToggleButton
    android:id="@+id/tbX"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:checked="true"
    android:text="@string/play"
    android:textOff="Pause"
    android:textOn="Play" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

This is my Class

```
     package com.CorpoServe.bvgindialtd;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URI;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;

public class ReportViewer extends ActionBarActivity {

List<String> ls= new ArrayList<String>();
int counter=0;
Handler hnd;
ToggleButton tb;
WebView bz;
public String GetIntenetData(String URL) throws Exception{
    BufferedReader in=null;
    String data=null;
    //URL="http://corposerve.com/ActionPage.asp?action=auth&uid=abc&pwd=abc";
    try{
        HttpClient cl= new DefaultHttpClient();
        URI ws= new URI(URL);
        HttpGet rq=new HttpGet();
        rq.setURI(ws);
        HttpResponse rs = cl.execute(rq);
        in= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(rs.getEntity().getContent()));
        StringBuffer sb=new StringBuffer("");
        String l ="";
        String nl= System.getProperty("line.separator");
        while((l=in.readLine())!=null){

        sb.append(l+nl);

        }
        in.close();
        data=sb.toString();
        return data;
    } finally {
        if(in!=null){
            try{
                in.close();
                return data;
            }catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_report_viewer);

     if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        }

     try {
        String Url="http://203.90.76.206/newmis/GetReportList.aspx";
        String ss[]=GetIntenetData(Url).split(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
        ls.clear();
        for(String s:ss){
            String[] x =s.split(Pattern.quote("*"));
            ls.add("http://203.90.76.206/newmis" + x[0]);

        }
        bz= (WebView) findViewById(R.id.Brz);
        bz.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        bz.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
        bz.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        bz.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        bz.loadUrl(ls.get(0));
        tb=(ToggleButton)findViewById(R.id.tbX);
        counter=0;

        hnd=new Handler();
        Runnable rnbl=new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(10000);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        // TODO: handle exception
                    }
                    hnd.post(new Runnable(){

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            if (tb.isChecked()){
                            counter++;
                            if (counter>=ls.size()-1){
                                counter=0;
                            }

                            bz.loadUrl(ls.get(counter));
                        }
                        }
                    });

            }
        };

        new Thread(rnbl).start();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        //e.printStackTrace();
        Toast t= new Toast(getApplicationContext());
        t.setText( "1:" + e.getMessage());
        t.show();
    }

     final Button nxt= (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnNext);
     final Button prv=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnPrev);
     nxt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            counter++;
            if(counter>=ls.size()){counter=0;}
            bz.loadUrl(ls.get(counter));

        }
    });
     prv.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            counter--;
            if (counter<0){counter=ls.size()-1;}
            bz.loadUrl(ls.get(counter));
        }
    });
     tb.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(tb.isChecked()){nxt.setEnabled(false);prv.setEnabled(false);}else{nxt.setEnabled(true);prv.setEnabled(true);}

        }
    });

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.report_viewer, menu);
    //MenuItem itm=menu.findItem(R.menu.report_viewer);
    //itm.setVisible(false);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to admit I haven't tried your code but there are already a bunch of things you should take care of. First, you shouldn't call your `GetIntenetData()` [sic] method from your Activity's `onCreate()`. This blocks your UI thread, and it shouldn't.

Here are some useful resources for a beginner:

- Activity lifecycle: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html
- Processes and Threads: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html (as explained there, using `AsyncTask` is generally a good way to do work in the background, such as loading web contents)

Basically you should initialize your activity and the view components in `onCreate()`, then you can launch an `AsyncTask` from `onResume()` to load your content in the background.

Finally, from quickly reading your code it seems that you are only calling your `Runnable` once, which would explain why you are only loading one page.

Comment: To avoid blocking UI thread i have taken care by adding StrictMode.ThreadPolicy thing. so it was already taken care. How every i agree i didnt take care of onResume. it worked thanks.